# saving Json data to coredata IOS and show it in UITableView simultaneously

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am new to IOS Xcode programming.Currently I am working on an app which uses Json data.
The app reads Json data which may be very large in size. I need to parse the data and store it to Core Data so that when the app runs the next time it can simply read data from there saving lots of time. I have tried using `dispatch_async` but the UI seems to get frozen while data is being saved also leading the app to crash.
I used `ASIHTTPRequest` to read and parse Json data which works just fine but its the part where I have to save Data to core data and load it in `UITableView` simultaneously which is proving to be pain. 
If anyone can help me with this I'll be very grateful.

Here is my code

```
NSString *connectionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?song_id=%@", SERVER_STRING, URL_GET_SONG_LIST, lasSongID];

NSLog(@"COnnection String is:\n%@", connectionString);
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:connectionString];

//The actual request
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Becoming the request delegate
//To get callbacks like requestFinished: or requestFailed:
[request setDelegate:self];
NSLog(@"Fetching Dataaaaaaaa from %@",url);

// Fire off the request
[request startAsynchronous];

-(void) requestFinished: (ASIHTTPRequest *) request 
{
    NSString *theJSON = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Dataaaaaaaa,%@",theJSON);
    NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [theJSON JSONValue];

    if ([[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"Message"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
    {
        [songsArray addObjectsFromArray:[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"Message"]];

        if (songsArray.count > 0) 
        {
            dispatch_async (bgQueue, ^(void){
                [self saveDownloadedSongs];            
            });
        }
    }
}
```

saveDownloadedSongs--> saves Json to my core data after some validations

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an NSFetchedResultsController for your entity that you want to store

   ```
   @property (nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController fetchedResultsController;
   //Initialize it in your viewDidLoad
   ```
2. Your view controller should be your NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
3. Implement delegate method for NSFetchedResultsController

   ```
   - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   {
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
   ```
4. Implement your data source method for UITableView

   ```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
       return self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
   }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       return [self.fetchedResultsController.sections[0] numberOfObjects];
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

       if (cell == nil) {
           cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       }

       SomeObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cell.label.text = object.property
       return cell;
   }
   ```
5. Everytime you persist a new object your delegate will be triggered **automatically** and reloads the table, which now includes the new object.

**Edit:**

If you want to save time, create a new Master-Detail Application. In your MasterViewController you'll finde source code for step 1 and for smooth animations in step 3.